# Macro to colour stacked column chart based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba, stacked-bar-chart

I have a stacked column chart which has difference variables. I want to colour the chart based on these variables. My data is shown below:

[image: Data and chart so far]

Where a value in B3:B15 is equal to E2, I would like the colour to be blue, where it is not equal I would like it pink. Secondly, where B3:B15 is equal to F2, I would like the colour to be blue, where it is not equal, I would like it to be pink. The same rule applied for G2 and H2. Can someone help with coming up with code to do this as I am not having much luck. The start of the code which identifies the chart and identifies the data is below. I have a series of other code but not sure what is right / wrong currently.

```vb
Sub ColorChart()
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim series As series
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Assuming you have a chart object named "Chart 8"
    Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
    
    ' Loop through each series in the chart
    For Each series In chartObj.chart.SeriesCollection
        ' Loop through each point in the series
       'MsgBox (series.Points.Count)
      ' MsgBox (chartObj.chart.SeriesCollection.Count)
        For i = 1 To series.Points.Count
       MsgBox (series.Points(i).Name)

I have tried a series of other code, but I can't figure out what is working and what isn't.
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub StackedColumnChart()
    Dim oSer As Series, rngHeader As Range, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, aFola, aRef
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Select
    For i = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count
        Set oSer = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)
        ' Change color of series
        With oSer.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(160, 43, 147) ' modify as needed
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        ' Get data point and header range reference
        aFola = Split(oSer.Formula, ",")
        aRef = Split(aFola(1), "!")
        Set rngHeader = Sheets(aRef(0)).Range(aRef(1))
        aRef = Split(aFola(2), "!")
        Set rngData = Sheets(aRef(0)).Range(aRef(1))
        ' Loop through each data point
        For j = 1 To rngHeader.Cells.Count
            If rngData.Cells(1).Offset(0, -1) = rngHeader(j) Then
                With oSer.Points(j).Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Chart.FullSeriesCollection method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.fullseriescollection?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm149194)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Series.Points method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.points?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm578104)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]